# How to use the Type class as type in variable declaration

Tags: vb.net

I want to make the same operations on different lists of controls of specific types. I could do it one type at a time, but I figured: "There's a bunch of these, so why not do this in a loop?" and now of course I'm wondering where I went wrong. The problem can be reproduced easily:

```
Dim myType As Type = GetType(TextBox)
Dim newList As New List(Of myType) ' this is not allowed
```

This is the specific error message: BC30002: Type 'currentType' is not defined

[image: error message]

Is there a way to use an object of the Type class as a type, or to do a similar maneuver which would let me do something like this:

```
For Each currentType As Type In {GetType(myCustomType), GetType(anotherCustomClassType)}
    Dim newList As New List(Of currentType)
    ' do stuff
Next
```

Comment: You can instantiate generic types at runtime using a type parameter contained in a variable.  You're still going to have problems referencing them, though, unless it's through a non-generic interface (or a variant interface parameterized on some sort of common base).  I've only done this as part of a factory setup where I was verifying that a type read from an assembly had a specific generic base (generally parameterized on itself as with the CRTP).  If you're interested in learning more, look up `Type.MakeGenericType`.

Comment: @Craig It _is_ interesting. I don't think I can use it in a declaration, though. Still interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't. When you create a generic `List`, you must specify a data type. A `Type` object is not a data type. It's an object that contains information about a data type. Basically, when you create a `List(Of T)` you can only fix `T` to be something that you could have passed to `GetType` in the first place. Both require data types.

You can't put data types in a list because they are not objects. What you could do is write a generic method that does what you want for one type, e.g.

```vb
Private Sub DoStuff(Of T)()
    Dim newList As New List(Of T)

    'Do stuff here.
End Sub
```

and then call that method and specify different generic types, e.g.

```vb
DoStuff(Of SomeType)()
DoStuff(Of SomeOtherType)()
'Etc.
```

You have to make individual calls though, because you need to specify the generic type.